# Is there a way to assign my computer multiple locations to move multiple files?

Tags: windows-10, file-transfer, file-management, move

My current issue is that when transferring photos and videos to my external hard drive, each transfer takes quite a while, and I must wait for the transfer to complete before I can transfer another file.

I am organizing literally hundreds of thousands photos and videos into folders on an external hard drive. Especially when moving a video, it can take anywhere from 10 seconds to 10 minutes depending on the size of the video. That can become extremely time consuming with not very much productivity.

Is there anyway to assign the computer (Windows 10) a "list" of where I want each file to go before it actually starts the action of moving them? I'm thinking of it similar to how a printer has a print que, which is just a list of files to print that you can add to, but for moving files to new locations.

Comment: Not without 3rd party software like for example [WIA-Loader](https://www.mortara.org/en/apps-software-2/windows/wia-loader/), so why don't you simply transfer everything first and then move to the correct folders in a 2nd step?

Comment: You know, I have no clue why I don't transfer everything first, and then move to the correct folder. Haha this is one of those moments when I have made something way too overcomplicated in my head, and missed an obvious solution. Thank you.